# How to delete specific li element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I'm having trouble deleting a certain `li` element when you click on the `X` in the div. Instead of deleting the one next to the `X` it just deletes all of the `li` elements. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    var toAdd = $("#listItem").val();
    $("ol").append("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>");
    $('ol').append('<div> X </div>')
  });

  $("#listItem").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Don't submit the form
      $("ol").append("<li>" + this.value + "</li>"); // append this.value
      this.value = ""; // reset the value field
    }
  });
});

$(document).on('dblclick', 'li', function() {
  $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");;
});

$(document).on('click', ' div', function() {
  $('li').toggleClass('strike').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by delete? o remove it from DOM or just strike out it

Comment: We need to see your HTML to give you a specific answer, but your issue is that you're selecting all `$('li')`, whereas you need to instead traverse the DOM to find the `li` related to the clicked close button. Something like `$(this).closest('li')`

Comment: please add relevent HTML to see the code in action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a query selector to detect html elements by the tag name `li`. This is not a unique selector so it will return all the elements that match the query.

In the context of a click event, the `this` keyword will refer to the thing that has been clicked. You can use it to select the specific element if you know the html structure. I'm not sure from your question what your html looks like, but if it were as follows you could use this code. Note you can pass a second parameter to `fadeOut` as a callback function to be triggered once it has completed if you want to remove the `li` from the DOM instead of just hide it.

**HTML**

```
 <ul>
     <li>text<div>X</div></li>
 </ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('click', ' div', function() {
     $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('strike').fadeOut('slow', function() { $(this).remove(); });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery selector is selecting all the `li` elements on the page. You need to identify the element that was clicked.

Take a look at this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/La7eh5Lu/

It shows how you can attach a handler to an event on a specific DOM element. You can use this to throw an event with the exact li element that has been clicked and then use that information to perform whatever action you want to.

Comment: yes thanks. I think i  need to add this keyword somewhere but i cant figure out where

Comment: I would change you approach.

When you add a `li` element, attach an onclick event handler to it with `.click()`. This will make it easier to determine which `li` object was involved in the click event.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).on('click', ' div', function() {
  $(this).prev('li').toggleClass('strike').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

This should delete the nearest previous sibling of the div with X in it.

Comment: This is not removing the li element, but just hiding

Comment: True, but looking at the OP's  code I think by "delete" he just means "hide".

Comment: You are probably right, but delete is more similar to "remove" than "hide"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove with fade, you have to `fadeOut()` and then `remove()` the element, otherwise it will jsut be hidden.

```
  $(this).closest('li').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
```

Check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bLsyx98e/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', ' div', function() {
      $(this).parent().find('li').toggleClass('strike').fadeOut('slow');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what html you have,but hope this can help you a bit

```js
$("#list a.clear").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="list">
  <li><a href="#" class="clear">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="clear">two</a><h/li>
  <li><a href="#" class="clear">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    var toAdd = $("#listItem").val();
    $("ol").append("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>");
    $('ol').append('<div class="remove"> X </div>')
  });

  $("#listItem").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Don't submit the form
      $("ol").append("<li>" + this.value + "</li>"); // append this.value
      this.value = ""; // reset the value field
    }
  });
});

$(document).on('dblclick', 'li', function() {
  $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");;
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).prev().remove();
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
</ol>

<input type="text" id="listItem">
<button id="btn2">Add</button>
```